# Fixing Jquery Waypoint

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-waypoints

Good day, I'm trying to teach myself Jquery waypoints and right now i'm having trouble trying to make it work. The idea is once the element is visible on the screen it would display an "alert" saying "this element is visible". But whenever i scroll down the alert doesn't seem to appear. Here is a sample of my code.

**HTML**

```
<section class="container">
    <div class="sixteen columns item"></div>
    <div class="sixteen columns item"></div>
    <div class="sixteen columns item"></div>
    <div class="sixteen columns item"></div>
    <div class="sixteen columns item"></div>
    <div class="sixteen columns item"></div>
    <div class="sixteen columns item"></div>
    <div class="sixteen columns item"></div>
    <div class="sixteen columns item"></div>
    <div class="sixteen columns item thing entry" id="example-basic"></div>
</section>
```

If i place this part on top of the others it seems to be working and the alert is displayed

```
<div class="sixteen columns item thing entry" id="example-basic"></div>
```

**Javascript**

```
<script>
$('.entry').waypoint(function() {
   alert('The element appeared on the screen.');
});
</script>
```

Comment: okay but what is the issue? i think you forgot to mention.

Comment: edit my post and added the issue :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to wrap it with doc ready handler:

```
<script>
   $(function(){
      $('.entry').waypoint(function() {
         alert('The element appeared on the screen.');
      });
   });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The Waypoints default is to run the function when the element hits the **top of the viewport**, not **appears on screen**. You can change that default behavior by passing the `offset` option:

```
$('.entry').waypoint(function() {
  alert('The element appeared on the screen.');
}, {
  offset: 'bottom-in-view' // or '100%'
});
```

`'bottom-in-view'` will fire when the entire element has come into view. `'100%'` will fire when any part of the element hits the bottom of the viewport.